# Django: assertIn(instance, queryset) fails although instance is in queryset

Tags: django, testing, django-models, orm

I have a unittest where the first line is ok, while the second fails:

```
self.assertIn(activity.id, Activity.objects.all().values_list('id', flat=True))
self.assertIn(activity, Activity.objects.all())
```

I just don't understand why the second one fails. Isn't the same as the first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution:

`activity` was from the "real" model, while `Activity` is a [ProxyModel](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/models/#proxy-models)